# Get current Value of Svelte Store Variable in Ts/Js File

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-store

I've tried to get the current value of a variable in my Svelte Store file in an other TS File with the 'get' Method.
But it seems like the 'get' method is only getting the inital value of the variable in the Store and not the current value.

```
//stores.ts
export const variable = writable([]);
```

This variable is being changed after a while.

*After* the Variable is being changed by my Application (let's say it got changed to 42) im trying to get it via the 'get' method:

```
//test_file.ts
import { variable } from './stores'

let value = get(variable)
console.log(value) //[] and not 42
```

So it seems like the 'get' Method is just getting the inital Value of the Store Variable and not the current one.
Does anyone know how to access the current value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the Value, you have to **subscribe** to the Variable.

You can do this with the following code.

```
    let subscriptedVariable:any;

    // "variable" is the variable configured in the stores.ts
    variable.subscribe((value) => (subscriptedVariable = value));
```

Now you have the Value of the stored Variable "variable" in the local Variable "subscriptedVariable".

Answer (score 1):

It is actually getting the current value at the point those lines are executed.  What you probably want to do is read the store value at the point some function is called.

```js
export function doSomething() {
  const value = get(variable);
  // more code here
}
```

Now, every time you call `doSomething` from your components it will read the store and get the current value.

Comment: I've tried your solution but if I log value I still receive an empty Array. I'm trying to get the Value in a Playwright Test file and at that point where I am calling the doSomething function I get an empty Array. However, when i'm going into that specific state of my application on the Localhost, not in the Playwright Test Enviroment, and I log the store variable 'variable', I get the correct value.

Answer (score -1):

Do update the variable value with `update` or just simple reassigning the other value?

Comment: I want to access the store variable and not manually set/update it. My Application is a litte more complex so I can't just simply update the variable. I have to access it via the store.

Comment: This isn't really an answer; if you need to ask the original poster something, please use the comment function instead. Thanks!